# Collectionview Fixed Cell Spacing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've been looking for how to make `UICollectionView` have a fixed spacing between its cells, but have not found a solution so far.

I have a `UICollectionView` which consists of two columns, and all the cells have the same width, but they vary in height. I have only one section in this `UICollectionView`.

I have set the minimum spacing to 10(which is the value I want between cells vertically), but the system is seemingly randomly stretching the vertical space.

What I would like to achieve, is the effect Wikipedia for iPad has: different article tiles with the same width, but adjustable height according to need, yet all the cells are spaces evenly vertically. (I don't mind leaving space at the very end, but I don't want extra spaces in the middle)

How should I achieve this? I would accept third-party libraries if it is easy to migrate existing `UICollectionViews`(and it's open-source, of course).

Comment: Use delegates method of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout . your problem solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, so the reason after all is that the spacing that I've set was the *MINIMUM* spacing between cells. The collectionView could use whatever spacing needed to align cells on the same row, as long as it's not less than the minimum.

Answer (score 4):

In swift 3,
you can implement this delegate method for cell spacing in collectionView :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
    // Give cell width and height
    return CGSize(width: 750, height: 320)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat{
    // splace between two cell horizonatally
    return 50
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat{
    // splace between two cell vertically
    return 100
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{
    // give space top left bottom and right for cells
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 100, bottom: 100, right: 100)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Due to the server temporarily unavailable, I could not have your answer tested, but I will once possible.

Comment: Strangely, nothing changes. Is there anything that I might have missed?

Comment: please check all delegate properly set and those methods are called or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have fixed inter item spacing on UICollectionView you can use the custom layout below. Note: I've created this layout for fixed height cells and .vertical scroll direction.

```
class CollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    guard let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else {
        return nil
    }
    
    var startX: CGFloat = 0.0
    var startY: CGFloat = 0.0
    let contentWidth = collectionView?.frame.width ?? 0
    
    for layoutAttributes in layoutAttributes {
        let size = layoutAttributes.size
        if (startX + size.width + minimumInteritemSpacing) > contentWidth {
            startX = 0
            startY += size.height
            startY += minimumLineSpacing
        }
        let origin = CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY)
        let frame = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
        layoutAttributes.frame = frame
        startX += size.width + minimumInteritemSpacing
    }
    return layoutAttributes
}
```

}